# What's the fastes way to take big numbers (e.g. 1900234) and put commas after every three digits?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am working on an internship project that, although it's not focused on performance, I would want to be as fast (and lean) as possible. So far, I have one working version (with a bug) and one concept of the aforementioned function:

**V1 (BUG: Can't handle numbers with dots and commas.)**

```
function addCommas(nStr) {
  if (isNaN(nStr)) {
    throw new Error(`${nStr} is NaN`);
  }
  // Alternative: isNaN(nStr) ? throw new Error(`${nStr} is NaN`) : nStr += ``;
  nStr += ``;
  // If the input is of the form 'xxxx.yyy', split it into x1 = 'xxxx'
  // and x2 = '.yyy'.
  let x = nStr.split(`.`);
  let x1 = x[0];
  let x2 = x.length > 1 ? `.` + x[1] : ``;
  let rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    // x1 takes the form 'x,xxx' - no matter how long the number,
    // this is where the commas are added after every three digits.
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, `$1` + `,` + `$2`);
  }
  return x1 + x2;
}
```

**V2 Concept (looks slower but no known bugs)**

```
function addCommas(nStr) {
  if (isNaN(nStr)) {
    throw new Error(`${nStr} is NaN`);
  }
  nStr += ``;
  // Remove any potential dots and commas.
  nStr = nStr.replace(`.`, ``);
  nStr = nStr.replace(`,`, ``);
  // Split the number into an array of digits using String.prototype.split().
  // Iterate digits. After every three, add a comma.
  // Transform back into a string.
  return nStr;
}
```

Comment: why template literals? instead of real strings? templates are interpreted and slower.

Comment: I don't have that much JS experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the function toLocaleString:

```
const b = 5120312039;
console.log(b.toLocaleString()); //"5,120,312,039"
```

Comment: You can specify the locale as an [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var str = "123456789";
var result = [...str].map((d, i) => i % 3 == 0 && i > 0 ? ','+d : d).join('').trim();
console.log(result);
```